# SSRS report with different data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have an SSRS report where I receive a table of files which stuck in transition. In that table may be more than one user who should do some action. I want to create one report and change (using SQL query) the user for whom this table generated and send personalized reports to them. We are using MS SQL Standard 2014. So I've found a workaround on how to generate a data-driven subscription and it works fine. But reports which will send by RS  still contain information for all users. I mean report which contains all people who should do some stuff is sending only for people mentioned in this report, not to all users in the base. Because of this, it's not usable and it really hard to find which files belong to you.

I'm stuck on the step: Is it possible for each iteration of running the same report to use different user names to generate personalized reports? For example except [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLndB.png), I want users will receive [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWtSz.png).

For data-driven subscription I used this [instruction](http://thoughtsfrommylife.com/creating-data-driven-ssrs-reports-in-sql-server-standard-edition/#:%7E:text=A%20data-driven%20subscription%20lets,not%20have%20any%20meaningful%20results).

I know the simple way is to create many reports for one user and trigger it, but I think it's monkey business.

Comment: Ok googling gives me some results, what I needed is called Report Parameters. But IDK how to call it through SSRS task schedule.

Comment: For this kind of task I suggest creating a SSIS solution which first queries the list of users as you mentioned, loops through this list and then renders the report by passing the user as parameter. This report should be stored on some drive on the server. After this you can use a smtp send mail task in SSIS to send this mail to the corresponding user. In the next loop cycle, the file will be overwritten and sent to the next recipient and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Thank's to Tyron78. I tried SSIS and it 100% what I needed.
I've built a small workflow with SQL query and c# script. c# script generates pdf files and sends them to a list of users which emails users get from SQL query.